# Cakephp 3.0 installation in ubuntu

Tags: cakephp-3.0

How to install cakephp-3.0 in ubuntu?

Older version of cakephp we don't have any more installation steps. We are just downloading the cakephp folder and extract into the www root folder and started working on that. But right now in the latest version of cakephp  having some installation steps. what is it?

Comment: Why can't you checkout the same on Cakephp official website : http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html

I think, you will not going to get such a detailed installation process here.

Comment: I was working with same link which you have mentioned above. but I have faced the the some issue related to the extension and all. I have fixed the and the project is working fine to me. So just I want to help others to do the things vary easily. I already given the answers as well. Refer the answer bellow.  Thank you

Answer (score 5):

**Cakephp Installation Requirement**

1. PHP 5.4 or greater
2. mbstring extension package
3. intl extension package

**Following are the additional steps for Cakephp 3.0 installation apart from the Cakephp 3.0 Manual, so that it can be very helpful for easy installation:**

### Step 1:

Download and install the Composer by running the following command

`curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`

### Step 2:

Install intl and mbstring extension packages by running the following command

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
sudo apt-get install mcrypt php5-mcrypt
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

### Step 3:

Edit the /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini file and add following lines

File Path : /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

```
extension = mcrypt.so

extension = intl.so
```

### Step 4:

Restart apache server, can use the below comment for restart the server

```
service apache2 restart
```

### Step 5:

Get a new CakePHP application by running following comment (You can place your project where ever you want. There is no restricted we have to add all our application code inside the www root folder):

```
sudo php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist -s dev cakephp/app [app_name]
```

the above comment will create one application with all relevant files required for application.

### Step 6

Make sure the directories logs, tmp and all its subdirectories in your CakePHP installation are writable by the web server (application folder).

### Step 7

Execute the following code, And we will be using CakePHP’s console to run PHP’s built-in web server which will make our application available at  http://localhost:8765/

```
bin/cake server
```

eg: my application name is "cakephp3_0" so the you have to run the above comment inside the application.
      cakephp3_0$ bin/cake server

The above code will make running the server and if you want to access the project you go to the url http://localhost:8765/

If you want to exit from the server use the key  `CTRL+C`

Happy coding....:)

Answer (score 2):

****CakePHP 3.0 Installation ****

CakePHP is simple and easy to install.

Minimum Requirements to install cakePHP

## 1. HTTP Server. For example: Apache. Having mod_rewrite is preferred, but by no means required.

## 2. PHP 5.5.9 or greater (including PHP 7).

## 3. mbstring extension.

## 4. intl extension.

if you dont have php installed on your machine then open terminal and type in this command.

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
```

**to install intl extension type this command**

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

## now go to your php.ini file and add following lines:

```
extension = mcrypt.so

extension = intl.so
```

note:- php.ini file can be reached through this path:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

**#now you have to install composer**,which is a tool for dependency management in PHP. It allows us to declare the libraries your project depends on and it will manage (install/update) them for us.

> before you install composer restart your apache server by typing this command:

```
service apache2 restart
```

note:

> suppoose u want to run CakePHP on localhost then follow this path:

```
cd /var/www/html/
```

> continue following steps in this path
>
> Now to install composer type these commands one by one on  terminal:

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" > composer-setup.php

php -r "if (hash('SHA384', file_get_contents('composer-setup.php')) === 'fd26ce67e3b237fffd5e5544b45b0d92c41a4afe3e3f778e942e43ce6be197b9cdc7c251dcde6e2a52297ea269370680') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); }"

php composer-setup.php

php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

u have succussfully intsalled composer on your /var/www/html/

> now type this command to create new CakePHP applicaton

```
php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app App_name
```

> In place of **App_name** you can give your application name

**Once Composer finishes downloading the application skeleton and the core CakePHP library, you should have a functioning CakePHP application installed via Composer. Be sure to keep the composer.json and composer.lock files with the rest of your source code.**

> now in your /var/www/html/ folder there will be a folder called **App_name** or the name you gave it to your application
>
> now we will be using CakePHP’s console to run PHP’s built-in web server which will make your application available at http://host:port. From the app directory, execute:

```
bin/cake server
```

> now on your browser type :

```
localhost/App_name
```

> note:In place of App_name paste your appliaction name
>
> If you have problem redenring your page then you have tp perform following steps:

**URL Rewriting¶**

> If your CakePHP site still has problems with mod_rewrite, you might want to try modifying settings for Virtual Hosts. On Ubuntu, edit the file **/etc/apache2/sites-available/default** (location is distribution-dependent). In this file, ensure that AllowOverride None is changed to AllowOverride All, so you have:

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and type this command in your terminal:

```
 sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

> again restart your apache service

```
service apache2 restart
```

**now you have all set**

thank you.. enjoy now your ovan is ready  for CakePHP...

Comment: please feel free to ask if you have problem on installing CakePHP